# Freemarker : Convert unix timestamp string to date format string

Tags: datetime, freemarker

I am getting unix timestamp in String format in my ftl file. I want to reformat date to readable string such as "yyyy-MM-dd".

How should I convert timestamp to formatted date string ?

Answer (score 1):

I got date in required format using below code:

calBookingEntry.getStartTime()?number?number_to_datetime?string["yyyy-MM-dd"]